# How can I interchange(or swap) two numbers of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have an array of a given dimension. I want to swap  two given elements of the array. I tried to swap the two with the help of a temporary variable, but the result was bogus and confusing. Can someone suggest some other way of doing so? 
Also , it would be really helpful if someone told me why my current program is not working.

Comment: Your current program is not working because you wrote the wrong code. With the information given we can't be more specific.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: What was the code, and what was "bogus and confusing" about it!?  That is about as meaningless as you could make it.  If *your code* did not work as you expected, post it and you will get help very quickly.  We cannot tell what you did wrong otherwise.  It is such an odd way of asking a question, I suspect that in fact your homework is to do it by other means and this is your rather clumsy way of getting someone to do it for you.  It is a possible but almost entirely pointless exercise beloved of some tutors who like to encourage code tricks rather than clear code.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping using a temporary variable is the correct way.

There's no way to figure out what error you did to make it fail, since you didn't post any code.

In general for an array of type `T` we can swap the elements at positions `i` and `j` like so:

```
T x[N];
const T tmp = x[i];
x[i] = x[j];
x[j] = tmp;
```

This works for any type `T`, including `struct`s.